# stick footer to bottom if actual page height is greater than html height

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where I use several sliders on the page due to which the actual height of the page changes

Let's say my `html` height is 600px but due to some sliders the actual page height is 1000px

And because of this, when I try to stick the footer to the bottom using `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`, I have it placed at the end of the `html` height

I used an example to show how everything looks like for me

If I use `position: relative` then on other pages where the height is small, it will not be at the bottom

How can I stick the footer to the bottom of the page in this case?

I have also tried wrapping the entire `html` content in a class `.wrapper { height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column; }` and for the footer use `position: relative` and `margin-top: auto`

This kind of helped, but then there were problems with the blocks that come after the `html`, they lost their width

```css
html {
  height: 500px;
}

.main-content {
  padding: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  padding: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  padding: 40px 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="main-content"> MAIN CONTENT</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT</div>
<footer class="footer">FOOTER</footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flexbox`. Uncomment `height` property in `body` to see the changes.

Check the elements `html`, `body`, `main` and `footer` in the code below.

Resources: 
[CSS Tricks | Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) 
[CSS Tricks | Flexbox and Auto Margins](https://css-tricks.com/the-peculiar-magic-of-flexbox-and-auto-margins/) 
[Dev | Stick Footer to The Bottom of The Page](https://dev.to/nehalahmadkhan/how-to-make-footer-stick-to-bottom-of-web-page-3i14)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*height: 1000px;*/
}

header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: cyan;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <header>Header</header>
    <main>Main</main>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve this issue is to set a minimum height on the block level element before the footer and to ditch all the positioning.

Let's say that you'd want to have a footer that's `50px` high. Your element before that should be *at least* `100vh - 50px` high in order to cover the full height of the screen even if the content isn't that big. You can do this with [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.main-content {
    background-color: red;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 50px)
}

.footer {
    height: 50px;
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main-content"></div>
    <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

I took the liberty and simplified your HTML structure. You can place anything inside `main-content` and the footer will stay at the bottom. If you for example modify the code to have `min-height: 200vh` instead of the calc...

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.main-content {
    background-color: red;
    min-height: 200vh;
}

.footer {
    height: 50px;
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main-content"></div>
    <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

...you can see that the footer stays at the bottom of the page even if `main-content` is bigger than what I provided in the first snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Grid is awesome for these types of designs where you want to have a fixed footer/header/sidebar along with with some other scrolling content.

In the example below, there are 3 rows.  Using a fractional for the height (1fr) on the main content, it will essentially grow to fill whatever space is available in the grid, after taking into account the height of the other rows.  In this case, the footer has a fixed height and uses `max-content` for it's height, while the aside uses auto, so it grows to adjust to its contents.  Playing with the various [grid-template-rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows) is incredibly powerful.

Run the snippet below, and then choose the full page option to see how it works at different viewport sizes.

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto max-content;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.main-content {
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.content {
  background-color: #c9c;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.footer {
  background: #cec;
  height: 5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-content">
  <p><code>main</code> Grid row height is <code>1fr</code> so it has a variable height that adjusts to take up whatever the remaining height of the grid is after accounting for the other two row heights.</p>
  <p>Using <code>overflow-y: scroll</code> on this element also allows it to scroll vertically when needed to fit its contents</p>
</main>
<aside class="content">
  <p><code>aside</code> Grid row height is auto so it has a variable height that adjusts to the size of its content.</p>
</aside>
<footer class="footer">
  <p><code>footer</code> Grid row height is max-content.  The footer has fixed height and always "sticks" to the bottom of the viewport.</p>
</footer>
```